# how to increase width of child in ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am making one app on ViewPager. and I am trying to do increase and decrease width of ViewPager's child.Is it possible or not?if possible than help me advance in thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of child using LayoutParam, suppose you have TextView in your viewpager then in `instantiateItem()`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup vGroup, int position) {
     TextView tv = new TextView(context);
     // set as fill parent
     tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     // set as wrap_content
     tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // or by set as fixed size
     tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, 200));

     vGroup.add(tv);
}
```

Comment: But I just do multiple imageview in viewpager .when i am doing zoom on imageview in pager image cut on swiping.  so please tell me what can i do? advance in thanks

Comment: you need to customizing your imageview for moving the zoomed image in pager to disable change paging when image was zoomed so you can drag it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the padding option of the View pager, it will decrease the size of inner content

Comment: But I just do multiple imageview in viewpager .when i am doing zoom on imageview in pager image cut on swiping.  so please tell me what can i do? advance in thanks

Comment: edit your question and place snippet of your code, so we could help more